# Understanding the proof if the union and intersection of two sets are connected, then the individual sets are connected

Tags: general-topology

Proposition: "Let X be a topological space. Let A and B be two subsets of X such that: A and B are either both closed or both open, if A∪B and A∩B are connected, then A is connected and B is connected."

Here is the proof:

Suppose for a contradiction that A is disconnected. Assume both A and B are closed. Then there are closed, disjoint, non-empty subsets S,T of A such that A=SuT.
Since A∩B is connected, one of B∩S and B∩T must be empty, otherwise A∩B=(B∩S)∪(B∩T). WLOG assume B∩S=∅.
Now, since S and T are closed in A and A is closed in X, S and T are closed in X. Therefore, B∪T and S are closed non-empty subsets of A∪B. Obviously, (B∪T)∩S=∅ and A∪B=(B∪T)∪S, so A∪B is disconnected, contradiction.

Ok my question is, where was it used in the proof that A and B are closed and why does it matter that A and B are both closed or open? It seems like the proof works without that.

Comment: "Now, since $S$ and $T$ are closed in $A$ and $A$ *is closed in $X$*, $S$ and $T$ are closed in $X$".

Answer (score 1):

You use that $A$ is closed in $X$ to conclude that $S,T$ closed in $A$ implies they're closed in $X$. The same applies to open (and then you'd have used that $S,T$ were open in $A$ and then open in $X$ as $A$ is open etc. (using the standard fact that "closed in closed is closed" and "open in open is open" for subsets and subspaces)

An alternative proof uses functions and the [pasting lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pasting_lemma), which holds for two open or two closed sets:

Suppose $f: A \to \{0,1\}$ is continuous, where $\{0,1\}$ is discrete. As $A \cap B \subseteq A$ is continuous, $f\restriction_{A \cap B}$ is constant with value $i_0 \in \{0,1\}$. Now extending $f$ to $A \cup B$ by $f(x)=i_0$ for $x \in B$ as well we get a continuous function on $A \cup B$ by the pasting lemma (where we use that $A$,$B$ are either both closed or both open in $X$) and the connectedness of $A \cup B$ tells us the extended $f$, and so a fortiori the original $f$ too, is constant. QED

Comment: actually why does it even matter if theyre closed or not? It can still be shown that A and B are connected sets right?

Comment: @willyx888 No. Let $A=\Bbb Q \cup \{\sqrt 2\}$ and $B=\Bbb R \setminus \Bbb Q$. Then $A \cup B = \Bbb R$ and $A \cap B = \{\sqrt{2}\}$ are connected but $A$ and $B$ are not. So we need the assumptions!

Comment: In $\Bbb R$ if $A=(0,1)\cup (1,2)$ and $B=[0,1]$ then $B$ is closed, $A$ is open. And $B, A\cup B,$ and $A\cap B$ are connected but $A$ is not connected.

Comment: @DanielWainfleet yes, that's a nice example why $A$ and $B$ need to be the same type for the proof to work. You meant this for the OP right?

Comment: Yes, for the OP................